# Требуется ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Исходя из требований Трудового кодекса() если по истечении срока трудового договора трудовые отношения фактически продолжаются и ни одна из сторон не потребовала их прекращения, то действие трудового договора считается продолженным на неопределенный срок".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ИСХОДЯ ИЗ - это производный предлог. Обороты с предлогом «исходя из» обычно выделяются запятыми.

Но мне больше нравится в данном предложении его синоним " на основании"
*На основании требований Трудового кодекса  действие трудового договора считается продолженным на неопределенный срок, если по истечении его срока  трудовые отношения фактически продолжаются и ни одна из сторон не потребовала их прекращения.*